# Why isn't this laser at the Bunker showing up?

Tags: the-witness

So I have completed all the puzzles inside I think, including the elevator. I've activated the panel at the topmost part:

[image]

The laser mechanism is pointing at the summit of the mountain, yet no laser actually shows up. I've restarted my game several times and each time loading in it's been this exact same way.

[image]

I can't tell if I'm missing something further that I need to do in order to get it working, or if it's bugged?  There's only one power source wired to the laser which is activated already, so I can't seem to find out why it's not showing up.

[image]

Comment: Seems like a bug to me... start over and head the bunker to try again?

Comment: Agree. The only laser that bothered me was the desert laser, because once activated it points out in the middle of nowhere (which, of course, is intended). All the other lasers did not have anything special about them.